# Audio recording faulty (dropped frames?)

Tags: sound, kubuntu, audio-recording

I have a freshly installed Kubuntu 14.10 on an AMD A8-3850 Llano. The audio device for recording is a Logitech G430 Gaming Headset.

When I try to record audio, i.e. with `audacity` or `avconv`, it sounds as if frames are dropped. The recorded audio feels slightly shorter than expected, and there are "jumps".

How can I get audio recorded cleanly, with audacity as well as avconv?

My audio parameters for avconv were: `-f pulse -i alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G430_Gaming_Headset-00-Headset.analog-mono`.

The headset is connected via a USB hub. This particular USB hub is a Sitecom 10-port hub. Besides the headset it has two OmniKey CardMan 3121, one Sitecom (inside: Transcend) multi card reader and one Samsung Galaxy S3 connected to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem actually was that the Logitech G430 Gaming Headset was not connected directly but via a USB hub. The solution was to connect the headset directly to the USB ports on the main board.